How would I implement ros2_control with an ESP32 running micro-ROS
I am quite new to working with ROS2 and as my first project, I am working on a self-balancing two-wheeled robot.
This is my current system design :
Raspberry Pi 3A+ : Gets LiDAR data and publishes to /scan

Ubuntu 22.04
ROS2 Humble

Server/Host : Performs SLAM and navigation

Ubuntu Desktop (VM)
ROS2 Humble

ESP32 : Runs control algorithm

Micro-ROS

Robot : Hardware Components

2 stepper motors
MPU IMU
LiDAR

I have so far been working in simulations, where I use ros2_control to interface with the robot wheels. Yet I'm unsure of how to transition this to the real robot.
I have seen implementations of people using serial communication and hardware interfaces to use ros2_control to interface with the motors via a micro-controller.
Yet since the ESP32 supports micro-ros, I felt that maybe it could be simpler to just have it publish joint states and imu messages onto ROS topics, which the controller could use to obtain various transforms and whatnot instead of having to write hardware interfaces and configure serial communication.
Furthermore, since the ESP32 runs its' own control algorithm to stabilise the robot, I wouldn't want the controller like the diff_drive_controller to set the individual wheel velocities. Instead, I thought I would use the messages on the cmd_vel topic as velocity set-points that the ESP32 could use in its control algorithm.
Having had no experience beforehand I am unsure of what the simplest way of achieving this is.
Any links to guides/tutorials would be highly appreciated.
Thank you all!

im also suffering the same fate. Im using ros2 humble on a RPi 4 with a seeeduino xiao, an l298n and 2x12V DC motors with enocder. No IMU. ALso using an RPLidarA1M8. The approach that everyone else seems to go for with the arduino seems out dated and should adapt with the new micro-ros however there is severely limited tutorials and documentation online compared to the alternatives My plan is to have microros sub to the /cmd_vel topic, publish to /odom. All the "maths" is figured out internally. I have a few things working but the PID for motor control isn't working and i cant set the odometry

There is no out-of the box way to use micro-ros as hardware component for ros2_control. You could use the topic_based_ros2_control and send a simple topic to your hardware via micro-ros.
Fyi: The diff_drive_controller has no feedback loop for wheel velocities, it only solves the inverse kinematics (from body twist to wheel velocities) and calculates the odometry (wheel sensors to tf). If you choose to not use ros2_control, you would have to implement the kinematics in a new node.

Thank you so much for the response.
Regarding diff_drive_controller, does it mean I could use it to publish the odom transform without actually having knowledge of wheel positions/velocities?

if you configure open loop, then it uses the commands to calculate the transform (without any sensor feedback)

Ah I see. Could I also just use the robot state publisher and joint broadcaster to get from joint states to tf, and in that case just ditch the diff_drive_controller all together? In the sense that the ESP32 would just listen to the cmd_vel topic to receive its command velocities and publish to a joint states to a topic that joint broadcaster can listen to (via topic based control).  Im just not entirely sure about what the best way is to get data onto the tf topic.
Thank you so much.
